# Custom styled select box has become unclickable

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using [this jQuery plugin](http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/) to style a select box but while the styles apply, the select box has now become unclickable...

[Here is an example](http://www.graphictankclients.co.uk/brunch/register/), if you scroll down the "County" field and try and click it, nothing...

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: your link, does not work, give some more details

Comment: Which link? Both work for me

Comment: ok, it works now, hey may be some other css file is overwritting this styles, just try commenting/uncommenting  the files

Comment: what does the version on the end of the url do? I tried [with](http://jsfiddle.net/UAbFe/1/) and [without](http://jsfiddle.net/UAbFe/2/) and the one without works

Answer (score 0):

See the following:

### HTML

```
<select name="country">
    <option>country 1</option>
    <option>country 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your `select` element empty? Did you **style** the element properly? If you did not specify any style, the dropdown will look like a clean text element (`span`,`p`,etc.). **The customSelect plugin does not have default CSS styles.**

Try deleting the CSS in this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uxpWd/1/)**.

### Screenshot

[image]

---

Even though it does not seem like there's any problem with your file linking, try putting the jQuery link and the costomSelect links in your `head` tags.

### HTML

```
<select id="county">
    <option value="test">
        a
    </option>
</select>
```

### jQuery/JavaScript

```
$('#county').customSelect();
```

### CSS

```
.customSelect {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border: 4px solid #b7bfcf;
  background: url(http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/images/select-box-bg.gif) right center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
    min-width:100px;
}
.customSelectHover {
  border-color: #aeb7c9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 1px 1px 2px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 1px 1px 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 1px 1px 2px;
}
```